# Spark + cassandra : how to create a keyspace?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am going through [pyspark_cassandra](https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra).

But I don't see any way to create a table / keyspace => is it possible at all?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this package?

This package is from DataStax, which is the Cassandra driver for python.

Github:
https://github.com/datastax/python-driver

API Documents:
https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['your_cassandra_ip'])
session = cluster.connect()

session.execute('CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };')
```